# How to set up Aptana Studio 3 with a Bitbucket private repo

Tags: git, authentication, ide, aptana-studio

I have just started playing around with Git and would like to push a personal project to a newly created, private repo on Bitbucket using Aptana Studio 3. I tried to use the Git integration in Aptana but I couldn't figure out where to enter my username and password for Bitbucket anywhere. I tried using the `Team > Share Project` context menu but that keeps throwing the following message:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '207.223.240.181' to the list of known hosts.
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I'm pretty sure that's because my repo is private. However, I couldn't find a provision to provide any form of credentials for linking to a private repo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You used the SSH link to clone your repository. For this to work you need to do one of the following:

1. Use ssh-keygen to [generate a private key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git), and add the equivalent public key to bitbucket.
2. Just use https, and enter your username and password each time (or [store it in .netrc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/search/?queryString=netrc))

It doesn't matter that your repo is private, your problem is in authentication to bitbucket.